# Найти самый длинный путь в графе

Tags: c, алгоритм

Есть ли алгоритм обратный Дейкстры, который наоборот выводит самый длинный путь? Или можно ли как то изменить алгоритм Дейкстры, чтобы находил самый длинный путь?

Comment: Нет. Эта задача (если имеется в виду простой путь, и граф не DAG) -  NP-hard, т.е. придётся перебирать все варианты

Comment: Я так понимаю, граф ориентированный?

Comment: @MBo, что-то не то. Там надо проверить ответ на бесконечность (накручиваем по циклу положительного веса) и если не бесконечность, то модифицируем веса рёбер вычитая их из максимума - на получившемся графе можно запускать дейкстру и найденный путь - ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy можете поправить меня если не так? 
Если я правильно понимаю графы, то граф будет связной оринтеровочный, где вершины будут первая и последняя буква слов (которые будут вводить пользователь), а линии цепочка слов, 
Задание: написать код по мотиву игра в слова, те подается начальное слово(word) и группа слов(words) из которых будет состоять цепочка и надо составить самую длинную цепочку (По последней  букве начального слова(word) выбирается следующее слово, которое на неё начинается и так далее)

Comment: Эм.. Т. е. граф не взвешенный? А нафига тебе тогда Дейкстра? Это условие вообще никак с твоим вопросом не связано.

Comment: @Qwertiy я просто обдумываю алгоритм, вспомнила что есть алоритм Дейкстера, вот и спросила...
а вы можете подсказать алгоритм который поможет мне? просто уже который день сижу ломаю голову

Comment: [Wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8) c указанием на энпэхард в общем случае и с алгоритмом для DAG

Comment: @MBo спасибо большое!

Comment: @MBo я изучу статью,но это не совсем то тк у меня вершины могут повторяться,а значить путь не простой уже

Comment: @MBo, в твоей статье, насколько я вижу, в условии задачи сказано, что каждую вершину можно посещать не более одного раза. Потому и различие в сложности. А я говорил про вариант без этого ограничения, когда ответ либо бесконечность, либо легко находится.

Comment: @Qwertiy граф будет оринтеровачным вешенным

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну да, простые пути. Автор же вообще никак не описывал, что у него есть.

Answer (score 1):

4500й удалил ответ, но интернет помнит.

Надо добавить ещё одну проверку

1. При инициализации всех вершин метки всех вершин, кроме начальной, будут равны некоторому отрицательному числу (например -1). Это нужно для того, чтобы нормально определять максимальное значение (Дейкстра работает только с положительными рёбрами);

1.5 При обходе графа вместе с весом пути хранить и сам путь.

1.6 При визите сначала проверяем, что в накопленном пути нет вершины. Если есть, то визит в данную вершину невозможен

2. Далее делаем всё то же самое, что и в обычном алгоритме, но на сей раз мы изменяем значение метки следующей вершины, если оно МЕНЬШЕ суммы значения метки текущей вершины и значения ребра.

Comment: Ну и, естественно, при построении плана посещений, сначала отдавать предпочтение ребрам с более высоким весом

Comment: В условии не говорится, что одну вершину можно посещать только один раз. К тому же, очень похоже, что этот алгоритм не работает даже с этой оговоркой. А после твоего комментария это кажется ещё больше.

Comment: Если посещать больше одного раза , то невозможно найти самый длинный по путь, потому что для любого пути `S`, всегда можно будет найти более длинный путь `S'`. Пусть мы нашли некий путь `S=p1,p2,p3...pN`. Его всегда можно удлинить, если посетить любые две вершины ещё раз `S'=p1,p2,p3,p2,p3...pN`

Comment: "К тому же, очень похоже, что этот алгоритм не работает даже с этой оговоркой" Чойта? Имелось ввиду хранить не в вершине, а в "обходе"

Comment: Его можно будет удлинить, только если в нём существуют вершины, между которыми есть цикл с положительным весом. При наличии отрицательных весов у рёбер, такой цикл вполне может не существовать даже если вообще циклы в графе есть.